# UIButton background image not crisp

Tags: ios, image, uibutton, interface-builder, pixel

I'm setting the background image of a UIButton in Interface Builder.
For some reason this image doesn't render well and I end up with something not crisp at all.
The button is 65x65 and the image is 302x302 and has an '@2x' version.

[image: screenshot of the blurry image I get in the simulator]
*screenshot of the blurry image I get in the simulator*

Any idea on what I should do to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Is it the same image which you have attached in the question? Because attached image is having size 91x87.

Comment: No the attached image is just a screenshot of the blurry image I get on the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is 302 square, and the button is 65 square, then it is going to have to be scaled down by a factor of 4.65. This is going to spoil the quality of the displayed image. If you're using image assets for fixed size UI elements, they should be the same size.

Comment: Huh, I thought that scaling down from a high rez image would be a good thing. Apparently not... Anyway, thanks it looks fine now.